# Variance of a Portfolio

Tags: statistics, variance

If I randomly buy 3 different stocks in a series of orders in a Poisson distributed manner (rate = 50/hr), and I know the probability that I buy stock A, stock B, and stock C, the expected amount of money I spend on each order, and the standard deviation of each order. How would I find the variance for the total amount of money I spend on the stocks over the next hour?

I took the probability of a given stock multiplied by the standard deviation squared, then added each stock A, B, and C, then multiplied the sum by 100. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use the decomposition of multi-type Poisson processes: for a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ such that each event in the process is of type $j$ with probability $0\leqslant p_j\leqslant 1$ $($with $\sum_j p_j = 1)$, then the number of type $j$ events are independent Poisson processes with rates $\lambda p_j$.

Do you think you can finish?

Comment: In other words, the variance would be the same as the expected value, correct?

Comment: No. In other words, the money spent can be represented by a random variable $c_AN_A +c_BN_B+c_CN_C$, where $c_L$ is the cost of stock $L$ and $N_L$ counts the number of stocks of type $L$ that are bought. By the decomposition, each $N_L$ is an independent poisson process. So you need to calculate the variance of a sum of random variables.